# Is cantor set homeomorphic to the unit interval?

Tags: general-topology

Can anyone help me with this question?

> Is cantor set homeomorphic to the unit interval?

I (think that I) can see that there is an $f: C \rightarrow [0,1]_{inf}$ which is a surjective bijection (where $[0,1]_{inf}$ is the points in $[0,1]$ that has infinite binary representation) since we can view the cantor set as the set $\{0,2\}^\mathbb{N}$.
But, I cant see if this can be widened to a surjective onto map $f: C \rightarrow [0,1]$, and if there is, I can see why this function is continuous with a continuous inverse.
On the other hand, If the claim stated above is not true, I am not sure how to show that.

Thank you!
Shir

Comment: One of the two spaces is connected, the other isn't.

Comment: $C$ *is* however, homeomorphic to $[0,1]_{inf}$ (because $f$ is continuous, for example). And you *can* map $C$ onto $[0,1]$, but not injectively (the function is called devil's staircase or Cantor function).

Answer (score 5):

Those sets aren't homeomorphic: 
unit interval is connected, while cantor set isn't

Comment: In fact, Cantor is totally disconnected: its only connected subsets are singletons.