# Why any uncountable $G_\delta$ set of $\mathbb{R}$, has a subset homeomorphic to $[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, baire-category, lebesgue-measure

as a continuation to my question here: [Is cantor set homeomorphic to the unit interval?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621390/is-cantor-set-homeomorphic-to-the-unit-interval)
 I can't see how can it is be true that any uncountable $G_\delta$ set of $\mathbb{R}$, has a subset homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. Isn't the process described here, from John C. Oxtoby's book **Measure and Category**, similar to the construction of the Cantor set?[image: Lemma 5.1]

Thank you!

Comment: The text does not say the subset is *homeomorphic* to $[0,1]$. It only says that the subset can be mapped continuously onto $[0,1]$. The unit square is an example of a set that can be mapped continuously onto $[0,1]$ but is not homeomorphic to $[0,1]$; the set $[0,1] \cup \{2\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is another example.

Comment: Thanks. Can I also say that any set as described in that Lemma is not connected. It seems even totally disconnected to me. But I am not sure how to begin showing it.

Comment: Note that the irrationals form a G-delta subset of reals and no subset of irrationals can be homeomorphic to $[0, 1]$ because any such subset is totally disconnected. However, if you replace $[0, 1]$ by Cantor set, this will be true.

Comment: You should cite the book that this scan comes from.  As it stands you are committing plagiarism.

Answer (score 1):

To give this an answer, expanding on Carl Mummert's comment:

**It doesn't.**

Lemma 5.1 of your text asserts that each uncountable $G_\delta$ contains a nowhere dense closed subset $C$ that can be mapped continuously onto $[0,1]$, i.e. there is a continuous surjective map $f : C \to [0,1]$.  It is *not* asserted that $f$ is injective nor that it has a continuous inverse, nor that $C$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ via some other map.  In general it is not.  For example, if $E$ is the Cantor set, by considering connectedness one can see that any continuous $g : [0,1] \to E$ is constant, so no surjective $f : C \to [0,1]$ can possibly have a continuous inverse.